# Solving a simple PDE with different methods

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, boundary-value-problem

Consider the following PDE on the interval $(0,L)$ for function $f(x,t)$
\begin{equation}
 \partial_t f(x,t) = a(x,t) f(x,t),
\end{equation}
with a general known function $a(x,t)$. The Neumann boundary condition is $\partial_x f \big\rvert_{x=0,L} = 0$ and an initial profile $f(x,t=0)$ that satisfies the BC. A solution can be obtained through an integrating factor as
$ f(x,t) = f(x,0) ~ e^{\int_0^t du ~ a(x,u)}$.

Another way of solving this that I'm interested in is to use Fourier series. Note that, for consistency, the boundary condition on $f$ also implies that $a(x,t)$ should satisfy the same conditions over the boundaries. Let's expand both functions as cosine series:
\begin{equation}
  f(x,t) = f_0(t) + \sum_{j=1}^\infty f_j(t) \cos \left(\frac{j\pi x}{L}\right) 
\qquad 
\text{and}
\qquad 
a(x,t) = a_0(t) + \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j(t) \cos \left(\frac{j\pi x}{L}\right) 
\end{equation}
Then replacing these back to the PDE yields
\begin{equation}
 \partial_t f_j(t) = \sum_{|\ell\pm k| = j} a_\ell(t) ~ f_k(t)
\end{equation}
where I have used the trigonometric identity $2 \cos(\ell\pi x/L) \cos(k \pi x/L) = cos((\ell+k)\pi x/L) \cos((\ell-k) \pi x/L)$.

**Question:** Is there a way to write $f_j(t)$ as a function of $a_\ell$'s only (and the initial condition), and potentially relate this to the exponential solution through the integrating factor?

Comment: I mean, you can write
$$f_n(t)=2\int_0^1 f(x,t)\cos(n\pi x)\mathrm dx\\=2\int_0^1 f(x,0)\exp\left(\int_0^t a(x,t')\mathrm dt'\right)\cos(n \pi x)\mathrm dx$$
Is that good enough?

Comment: I recommend you to use an index different from the letter $i$ when asking things related with the Fourier Transform since it could get "quickly" confused with the imaginary unit number.

Comment: @K.defaoite that's a good point. I'm really interested in relating an expression like you wrote to the Fourier components of a(x,t). Or alternatively, how can one manipulate the Fourier solution to get to the solution given by the integrating factor? I suspect there should be a straightforward connection.